# What happens if a HTTP connection is closed while AppEngine is still running

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The real question is if Google App Engine guarantees it would complete a HTTP request even if the connection is no longer existed (such as terminated, lost Internet connection).

Says we have a python script running on Google App Engine:

```
  db.put(status = "Outputting")

  print very_very_very_long_string_like_1GB

  db.put(status = "done")
```

If the client decides to close the connection in the middle (too much data coming...), will `status = "done"` be executed? Or will the instance be killed and all following code be ignored?

Comment: Where is the HTTP request, is it your `print` statement?

Answer (score 0):

If the client breaks the connect, the request will continue to execute. Unless it reaches the deadline of 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

GAE uses Pending Queue to queue up requests. If client drops connection and request is already in the queue or being executed, then it will not be aborted. Afaik all other http servres behave the same way.

This will be a real problem when you make requests that change state (PUT, POST, DELETE) on mobile networks. On Edge networks we see about 1% of large requests (uploads, ~500kb) dropped in the middle of request executing (exec takes about 1s): e.g. server gets the data and processes it, but client does not receive response, triggering it to retry. This could produce duplicate data in the DB, breaking integrity of this data.

To alleviate this you will need to make your web methods [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence): repeating the same method with same arguments does not change state. The easiest way to achieve this would be one of:

1. Hash relevant data and compare to existing hashes. In you case it would be the string you are trying to save (`very_very_very_long_string_like_1GB`). You can do this server side.
2. Client provides unique request-scoped ID, and sever checks if this ID was already used.